# Convert data in "grouped" columns from long to wide / square format pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, reshape

Not quite sure how to describe what I'm looking for, so hopefully an example will help.

[image]

- Each row contains up to n sets of observations (here, n=4)
- The observations are grouped by (id, x, y)
- The id represents some sort of unique location and the x, y are related values

So, for example, in the first row (index=0), there are two observations, at id=5 (x=a, y=0) and at id=9 (x=a, y=1)

I want to reshape / pivot the data such that there is a column for every location with the corresponding x, y values (can be NA).

In this example, that would look like this

[image]

Here, looking at the first row again, (id=5, x=a, y=0) has translated -> (x_5=a, y_5=0) and (id=9, x=a, y=1) -> (x_9=a, y_9=1). There are no observations for any other locations. So those are `<NA>`

Have been trying all combinations of `.pivot` I can think of but can't manage it.

MRE to produce the example DataFrame's:

```
import pandas as pd

df_before = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [5, 'a', '0', 9, 'a', '1'],
        [5, 'b', '3', 6, 'c', '3'],
        [9, 'c', '4'],
        [2, 'd', '12', 6, 'a', '3', 9, 'c', '2', 4, 'a', '3'],
        [6, 'a', '3'],
        [5, 'b', '0', 9, 'a', '4', 4, 'd', '9'],
        [2, 'c', '2', 9, 'g', '5', 4, 'g', '8']
    ],
    columns=['id_0','x_0','y_0', 'id_1', 'x_1', 'y_1', 'id_2', 'x_2', 'y_2', 'id_3', 'x_3', 'y_3']
).fillna(pd.NA)

df_after = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'a', '0', pd.NA, pd.NA, 'a', '1'],
        [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'b', '3', 'c', '3', pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'c', '4'],
        ['d', '12', 'a', '3', pd.NA, pd.NA, 'a', '3', 'c', '2'],
        [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'a', '3', pd.NA, pd.NA],
        [pd.NA, pd.NA, 'd', '9', 'b', '0', pd.NA, pd.NA, 'a', '4'],
        ['c', '2', 'g', '8', pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, 'g', '5']
    ],
    columns=['x_2', 'y_2', 'x_4', 'y_4', 'x_5', 'y_5', 'x_6', 'y_6', 'x_9', 'y_9']
)
```

Comment: so you guarantee that in each row of `df_before` all `id_i` are different ? Do you have a list of all values that `id_i` can be?

Comment: Yes, all `id_i` are different (i.e. there is only one observation of each location per row). I don't know the what `id_i` can be beforehand though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your operation is essentially melt/wide_to_long, and pivot back:

```
out = (pd.wide_to_long(df_before.reset_index(), 
                stubnames=['id_','x_','y_'],
                i='index', 
                j='old_id'
                )
       .groupby(['index','id_']).first().unstack('id_')
       .sort_index(level=[1,0], axis=1)
)
out.columns = [f'{x}{int(y)}' for x,y in out.columns]
```

Output:

```
       x_2  y_2  x_4  y_4  x_5  y_5  x_6  y_6  x_9  y_9
index                                                  
0      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a    0  NaN  NaN    a    1
1      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    b    3    c    3  NaN  NaN
2      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    c    4
3        d   12    a    3  NaN  NaN    a    3    c    2
4      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a    3  NaN  NaN
5      NaN  NaN    d    9    b    0  NaN  NaN    a    4
6        c    2    g    8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    g    5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
def fn(x):
    m = x.notna() & ~x.index.str.startswith("id")
    return {
        f"{a}_" + str(int(x[f"id_{b}"])): v
        for (a, b), v in zip(map(lambda v: v.split("_"), x[m].index), x[m])
    }

x = pd.DataFrame(df_before.apply(fn, axis=1).to_list())
print(x[sorted(x.columns, key=lambda v: int(v.split("_")[1]))])
```

Prints:

```
   x_2  y_2  x_4  y_4  x_5  y_5  x_6  y_6  x_9  y_9
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a    0  NaN  NaN    a    1
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    b    3    c    3  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    c    4
3    d   12    a    3  NaN  NaN    a    3    c    2
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    a    3  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN    d    9    b    0  NaN  NaN    a    4
6    c    2    g    8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    g    5
```